# How to copy value of dataframe to another dataframe's last column/row

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe:

[image: First Dataframe]
AND dataframe:

[image: Second Dataframe]
How do I insert the value from the first dataframe into the bottom of the second dataframe? The column header will change each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t2 = t2.append(table10.iloc[0], ignore_index=True)
```